# Map an objects type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I am looking for a way of a "mapped" object type in typescript.

I have a the following typings:

```js
interface Factory<T>{
     serialize: (val: T)=>void,
     deserialize: ()=>T,
}
interface MyDict{
     [key: string]: Factory<any>
}

function deserialize(dict: MyDict){
     let mapped = {};
     for(let k in dict){
          mapped[k] = dict[k].deserialize();
     }
     return mapped;
}
```

What I want is that the return type of map is correctly determined.

So when doing this:

```js
let mapped = map({
    foo: {deserialize: ()=>'hello world'}, 
    foo2: {deserialize: ()=>123}, 
    foo3: {deserialize: ()=>({foo4: 'foo4'})}
});
```

mapped should be typed as `{foo: string, foo2: number, foo3: {foo4: string}}`.

Comment: Given `MyDict` is not generic (and `map` is not generic either) - it's unlikely you can have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a mapped type. The function will also need to be generic in order to capture the actual type of the argument:

```
interface Factory<T>{
     serialize?: (val: T)=>void,
     deserialize: ()=>T,
}
interface MyDict{
     [key: string]: Factory<any>
}

type FactoryReturnType<T extends MyDict> = {
    [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]['deserialize']>
}

function deserialize<T extends MyDict>(dict: T){
     let mapped = {} as FactoryReturnType<T>;;
     for(let k in dict){
          mapped[k] = dict[k].deserialize();
     }
     return mapped;
}

let mapped = deserialize({
    foo: {deserialize: ()=>'hello world'}, 
    foo2: {deserialize: ()=>123}, 
    foo3: {deserialize: ()=>({foo4: 'foo4'})}
});

mapped.foo3.foo4
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=27&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGKLAeygTwDwAqAfAN4BQyllAztMHADbABeEA-AFzIAUAbo1wIBKALxFemYABMANBSrIpEWlHpNWXbqKIE5AXzKhIsRCgCyOACLAEYcguQBtANYQcXamFUgA5gF0udFtsfDgQHCIyAzIwHAAHFCCsXAAlCDAAVygQAniIQmQIAA9IEClqZAtrWyJkEWR7KkcAaWRQZFccTBhkAgDkNMzs3ITCFr9HAHIlFTUWCEm-SOiYDJBbYEwQRWU6RnmC4tLyyqsbMCJuKXPBIUaqBnTkAFs4OISpOoa9ZDgKpJCgyyOTyhCIAG5wfIqDBsNxHmAOm1ttdbHdoQ5KK93hApC4-F9UWB8QA6GZ7dQQLRQhwGBxQdLAl5vD5Q6II5k4z71cmqfasbj3ZCwzBcEi8uYaHjaSYACwgDAYmGQAHdsAwpJM9DJkBiRQAmMUS-kQTTaACM+oAzNrdQoRVajbs+ZSzWJBSKACxcSZerVCAx6IRQsjYj4kh0RzCYT1AA)

Comment: This almost seems to be the solution. However I had a bit of an unclear part in my question. Instead of just a "factory" function, I actually have a generic Interface with multiple properties derived from <T>, the factory or in my case deserialize function is just one of them. I updated my example accordingly.

Comment: @LucaAdrian updated the answer. Sorry the initial code was not 100% consistent between call and definition so I took some decistions.

Comment: Already tried that, just made a typo, but works wonderfully now ^^. So thanks a lot.